# Does dying in Richter Mode end my run?

Tags: dead-cells

I unintentionally started [Richter Mode](https://gamerant.com/dead-cells-richter-mode-unlock-how-return-to-castlevania-dlc/) by freeing Richter then later examining his cage. Now I'm playing as Richter in a different area without any of my items or upgrades.

If I die as Richter will my run restart from the Prisoner's Quarters? Or will I be able to resume my existing run from before I examined the cage?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Dying in Richter Mode will not end your run. You will instead be sent back to the cage room in Dracula's Castle. The cage will no longer be interactable, meaning you cannot try Richter Mode again in the same run.

Source: I died after posting this question.